# How to remove any site (Name and Location entry) from the "Available Software Sites" section in Eclipse using p2 director command?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

How to remove any site i.e 'Name and Location entry' from the "Available Software Sites" section in Eclipse using p2 director command.

However I am manually able to remove it by selecting above it, Eclipse->Help->Install New Software..->"Available Software Sites" -->Select above any Name,Location-->Remove

But I need to perform the same by using eclipse p2 director command.Given snap shot image description below.

[image]

Comment: I want to know how one can manage the list of available software sites programmatically. how can be any site can be removed from "Available Software Sites" in eclipse. Thanks in  advance- Murali